# Wine wont open Windows setup.exe

Tags: software-installation, windows

I am trying to install Windows 10 from my cd in Linux but every time I click on the `setup.exe` my Wine app wont open it. It just loads for a little bit and then still does nothing.

Comment: you cant not install windows 10 within wine

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I install Windows after I've installed Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6317/how-can-i-install-windows-after-ive-installed-ubuntu)

Answer (score 3):

You cant install windows 10 with wine
Either install vmware / virtualbox in linux and install windows 10
or make a partition with gparted and dual boot  the windows 10 in the particular partition

refer this

[How can I install Windows after I've installed Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6317/how-can-i-install-windows-after-ive-installed-ubuntu)